# multiprocessing python child process not running?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, daemon, snmp, child-process

My program needs a snmp trap listener. It needs to continuously receive snmp traps and perform further calculations on them. I am using `multiprocessing` module of python.

Right now, my program looks something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from snmpListener import snmpCompare
def main():
    execute()

def execute():
    try:
        p=Process(target=snmpCompare)
        p.start()
        #my code that runs here
        #it is basically sending commands to my server
        #which sends snmp alerts as response to my commands
        p.join()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt,SystemExit):
        p.terminate()
```

In snmpListener.py,

```
import multiprocessing

def trapListener():
    snmpTrap= receiveSnmpTrap()
    q.put(snmpTrap)

def snmpCompare():
    f=open('Alerts.txt','w')
    q=Queue()
    p=Process(target=trapListener, args=(q,))
    p.daemon=True
    p.start()
    while True:
        alert= p.get()
        f.write(alert)
        #perform calculation on 'alert' 
    p.join()
    f.close()
```

But, the code is running such that the child process from `execute()` function runs when it is created. Then all my commands in my parent process are getting executed on the server. The child process and parent process don't seem to running simultaneously. The alerts corresponding to the commands are not being received. i.e., The file "Alerts.txt" is empty.

I haven't been using `multiprocessing` module of python for a long time. In fact, I have worked very little on multiprocessing. I don't know where I am going wrong and I am a little confused. Any advice would be welcome.

UPDATE: I am calling `trapListener` when creating a child process from `execute` function. My calculations are being done in `trapListener` itself. I have also made `trapListener` a daemon process. My code is working now. Also there was an error being generated in child process due to which it was getting terminated. Hence Alerts.txt was empty.

Comment: Is `trapListener()` supposed to be a loop?

Comment: @Dan Yes, `trapListener()` is sort of an infinite loop. It runs continuously till we kill the process. I would have to close the command window or use a keyboard interrupt to stop it.